# Why am I getting a "Prelude.read: no parse" error when trying to print a list of integers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I tried to input a list of integers and print it out but I'm getting this error instead:
`Prelude.read: no parse`

Here's the code:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a list of integers:"
    input <- getLine
    let xs = read input :: [Int]
    putStr "The entered list is: "
    print xs
```

Input:

```
2 4 6 8
```

Expected output:

```
The entered list is: 2 4 6 8
```

Actual output:

```
The entered list is: Sample: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Comment: you'd need to enter `[2, 4, 6, 8]` for Haskell to read it as a list. Either that or write your own parsing function to convert such a space-separated string into a list.

Comment: The preferred way to read a line and then parse it with read is `readLn`, not `getLine`-then-`read`. Compare the behaviors of `main = do { x <- readLn; putStrLn "Have read line"; print (x :: Int) }` versus `main = do { xStr <- getLine; let { x = read xStr }; putStrLn "Have read line"; print (x :: Int) }` when you give an invalid input. This is not the source of your problem, just trying to let you know how to write better code.

Comment: @HTNW Is there also a specific way to read a single integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the following expression fails:

```
ghci>  read "1 2 3 4" :: [Int]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The `read` parser for the type `[Int]` expects to read a string containing a list in valid Haskell syntax:

```
ghci> read "[1,2,3,4]" :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4]
```

and won't accept a space-separated list of integers.  Reading a *single* integer still requires the single integer to be in valid Haskell format, but since this is just the usual way of writing an integer literal, it works as expected:

```
ghci> read "1" :: Int
1
```

So, what you can do is use the function `words` to break your string `"1 2 3 4"` into strings each containing a single integer:

```
ghci> words "1 2 3 4"
["1","2","3","4"]
```

and then `map` the `read` function over the resulting list of strings, one integer at a time:

```
ghci> map read (words "1 2 3 4") :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4]
```

The revised program:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a list of integers:"
    input <- getLine
    let xs = map read (words input) :: [Int]
    putStr "The entered list is: "
    print xs
```

*almost* does what you want, except it prints the list out in Haskell syntax:

```
Enter a list of integers:
1 2 3 4
The entered list is: [1,2,3,4]    <-- Haskell syntax for list
```

If you want to print the list the same way it was entered, you can replace `print xs` with:

```
putStrLn (unwords (map show xs))
```

Here, the expression `unwords (map show xs)` is the inverse of `map read (words input)`, and puts the list back into the original string format.